# Android Studio Error on Arch Linux

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, archlinux

i install Android Studio on my Arch linux.but after running I got this Erorr:

```
Sync with Gradle for project 'My Application' failed: Cause: error=13, Permission denied
```

this is my whole Log from Android Studio:
[download log file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00651858515834236559)

i install Android studio version 2.2.2 and useing my java package:

```
[sayres@Arch bin]$ java -version openjdk version "1.8.0_112" ,OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15) ,OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)
```

merci

Answer (score 0):

Try running android studio with root permissions using sudo. Another fix for this could include executing `chmod +x gradlew` in your project directory.

This second command just sets the execution flag for your grade wrapper.

Comment: i run from root but my problem is still here.Error:Cause: error=13, Permission denied. from my user i run chmod +x gradlew but nothing is change: <pre> -rwxr-xr-x 1 sayres users 4971 Jan  3 05:57 gradlew.  drwxr-xr-x 3 sayres users 4096 Jan  3 05:57 gradle<code>

Answer (score 0):

Android-sdk will is installed on `/opt/android-sdk` , so you have to run it as root, or better add a new user group.

The instructions are available on Arch Wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/android

Comment: in opt just exist on folder:  ls -l /opt/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Jan  3 05:04 genymotion. and does not exist android-sdk on it..im useing locally android sdk from another drive in my system

Comment: And by another drive you mean another partition mounted somewhere  with right usage access?

Comment: yes. I fix this problem with `chown -R root:root` command.thx